# Rails: Send ActiveRecord received at ajax success as param to another ajax

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Here's the situation: I have a view called "Dashboard" with a simple form and a "Draw Graphs" button. When I press this button I want to make two ajax requests that will return me the necessary data for my javascript to build two different graphs. The thing is that both requests will need to execute the exact same query on my database, and I want to avoid duplicating queries.

The way I'm currently doing this is by having my button fire a single ajax request that queries mysql for the necessary data, returning that data to my ajax success, and then passing that same data as params to two other ajax requests, which then use the data to generate the necessary structure for drawing the graphs.

It looks something like this:

**Javascript:**

```
$('#draw_graphs').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'single_query',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $('#myForm').serialize(),
        method: 'get'
    }).success(function(activeRecord) {
        ajax_graph1(activeRecord);
        ajax_graph2(activeRecord);
    });
});

ajax_graph1 = function(activeRecord) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'create_g1',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {active_record: activeRecord},
        method: 'post'
    }).success(function(g1) {
        create_g1(g1);
    });
};

ajax_graph2 = function(activeRecord) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'create_g2',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {active_record: activeRecord},
        method: 'post'
    }).success(function(g2) {
        create_g2(g2);
    });
};
```

**Rails:**

```
def single_query
  result = Data.where("etc... etc...")
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: result.to_json }
  end
end

def create_g1
  activerecord = params[:active_record]
  graph1 = {}
  activerecord.each do |ar|
    #do whatever with graph1
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: graph1.to_json }
  end
end

def create_g2
  activerecord = params[:active_record]
  graph2 = {}
  activerecord.each do |ar|
    #do whatever with graph2
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: graph1.to_json }
  end
end
```

The problem I'm having is that apparently you can't simply send an active record from controller to javascript and back to controller again, the structure seems to get changed on the way. While `single_query`'s `result` is of class `ActiveRecord_Relation`, when I pass it through the "javascript layer" it transforms into `ActionController::Parameters` class

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning makes sense: only want to hit the DB once. The issue is understanding how the "javascript layer" works with Rails. The AJAX call is getting an XHR Response object represented as JSON. This maps to a representation of your `active_record` in Rails but it's certainly not the same instance of an object in JS.

That being said, you should do what you need to do with the record on the Rails side and simply send the response to one AJAX call. In this case, have your `$('#draw_graphs').click(` AJAX call hit your controller in a corresponding `def draw_graphs` method. Have that method do the DB call, build each graph and pass both graphs back in a JSON hash (below). Then on the `.success(function(graphs)` parse the response and send the results to your 2 `ajax_graph` methods.

To build the JSON hash `format.json { render json: { graph1.to_json, graph2.to_json } }`

There are a few design optimizations here as well. You want to have a thin controller so consider **only** using the controller to sanitize/permit whatever params go into `result = Data.where(...)`. Pass those params to a method in a class that does the query and maybe has a helper method to generate the graphs. It looks like you can even just do a case statement in that helper method based on which graph it is building because the `create_g1` and `create_g2` code looks similar. Likewise, you can refactor the code in the JS as well.